# How can I increase the efficiency of my code (for loop)?

Tags: pandas, for-loop

```
def assignGroup(row):
    if row["E114"]=="Very good":
        return 1
    elif row['E114']=="Fairly good":
        return 2
    elif row['E114'] =="Bad":
        return 3
    elif row['E114'] =="Very bad":
        return 4
    else:
        return np.nan

outcome["leader"]=outcome.apply(assignGroup,axis=1)
```

Comment: btw, there is no "for loop" here )

Answer (score 2):

```
outcome["leader"] = outcome["E114"].map({
    "Very good" : 1,
    "Fairly good": 2,
    "Bad": 3,
    "Very bad": 4
})
```

Comment: It is much faster and works perfectly. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy's where:

```
import numpy as np
outcome["leader"] = np.where(outcome["E114"] == "Very good", 1, outcome["leader"])
outcome["leader"] = np.where(outcome["E114"] == "Fairly goo", 2, outcome["leader"])
outcome["leader"] = np.where(outcome["E114"] == "Bad", 3, outcome["leader"])
outcome["leader"] = np.where(outcome["E114"] == "Very bad", 4, outcome["leader"])
```

In Python loops should be last resource